# How to retrieve orders from Shopify through the shopify_api gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth-2.0, shopify

I am in the process of integrating an app to Shopify. I am using the `shopify_api` gem to retrieve orders, but I am finding that the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/Shopify/shopify_api) and [Readme](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api) does not cover much. And the [REST API documentation](http://docs.shopify.com/api/order) does not easily translate into `shopify_api` methods.

I have read that you can query for orders with params, but I get 50 more or less random orders returned when doing so:

```
puts ShopifyAPI::Order.find(:all, params: { order_number: 1606 }).size # => 50
```

I would also like to be able to retrieve orders from a given `created_at` date and from a given `order_number`.

Comment: Every one of your complaints is clearly addressed in the documentation and the gem sourcecode itself. Using ActiveResource effectively has been beaten to death with a few thousand blog posts. Use that resource pool to quickly figure out your problems. Inspect the gem code. It is clean, simple and will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: What a hostile comment on a genuine question. If I was able myself to read the answer from the documentation I would not have asked.

Comment: No one is questioning the genuine nature of your questions. And it was not a hostile comment. It was straight to the point. Your query is wrong as the docs show you what you can/cannot filter by. order_number is NOT included. Hence you get 50 records in lieu of any other valid filter criteria. 

The docs clearly showed you how to filter with dates:

    created_at_min
Show orders created after date (format: 2008-01-01 03:00)
created_at_max
Show orders created before date (format: 2008-01-01 03:00)

With a simple limit: 50 and page: # loop, grab all the orders, and filter them as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you a bit more info on where to look in the docs, this would be a good start:

http://docs.shopify.com/api/order#index

This gives you the full list of parameters you can filter/query by.

So for example:

```
puts ShopifyAPI::Order.find(:all, :params => {:status => 'any', :limit => 250})
```

Let me know if you have more specific question on a particular filter/query you are attempting.